# STL with a custom data type

Tags: c++, stl, deque, custom-data-type

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;

struct mystruct {
       int number1;
       int number2;
};

int main() {
    std::deque<mystruct> mydeque;

    mydeque.number1.push_front(77);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`push_front` is a method of deque not the number1 of structure `mystruct`..

The right way is :

```
struct mystruct {
       int number1;
       int number2;
mystruct(int n1, int n2) : number1(n1), number2(n2){}
};

int main() {
    std::deque<mystruct> mydeque;

    mydeque.push_front(mystruct(77,88));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the answer I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The deque is of type `mystruct` and you are trying to push an `integer`.

Answer (score 0):

you've declare `mydeque` as a container of `mystruct`s. it's initially empty, and certainly doesn't have a public member called `number1`.

```
mydeque.push_front({77, 88});
```